# Can ISO 8601 represent time intervals where start/end is a duration?

Tags: time, format, standards, iso8601

ISO 8601:2004 defines a [time interval format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) which can be expressed in various formats, including "c) by a start and a duration" and "d) by a duration and an end".

Going by the Wikipedia article alone, it seems like the examples only provide for `start` and `end` to be "time points", e.g. `2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/P1Y2M10DT2H30M` would be a time interval of 1 year, 2 months, 10 days, 2 hours and 3 minutes starting on 2007-03-01 13:00 UTC.

Is it possible to represent a time interval which start or ends after some duration? For example, `P1Y/P1Y2M10DT2H30M` would be the same duration but "starting" after 1 year.

Such syntax would be useful to model relative time intervals, especially when combined with repeating qualifies. For example, a monthly retirement payout could reasonably be expressed as `R/P65Y/1M`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression "P1Y/P1Y2M10DT2H30M" is not defined in ISO-8601. This paper mentions following four variants of a "time interval":

> a) Start and end are defined as points in time, example =>
>   2019-08-27/2019-08-29
>
> b) Duration without any fixed anchor on the (date)- or timeline,
>   example => P3D
>
> c) Start as point in time and a duration, example => 2019-08-27/P3D
>
> d) A duration and the end as point in time, example =>
>   P3D/2019-08-29

So your question "Is it possible to represent a time interval which start or ends after some duration?" can be answered by a clear "No". And honestly said, a *double* duration expression will confuse most users.

Comment: After writing the question, I can see how allowing `duration/duration` would be ambiguous about what element is the "start" or "end" and which one is the "duration", so it probably could never be expressed in the current syntax. Using 2 fields is necessary, then.